# LaTeX 2e environment that "knows" the name of surrounding environment

Tags: macros, environments, nesting

I'd like to have a LaTeX 2e-environment which when occurring inside another environment "knows" the name of the surrounding environment.
Is this possible?

I know that `\@currenvir` provides the name of the current environment.

I seek some sort of `\@surroundenvir`which provides the name of the surrounding environment.

E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{FOO}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                    {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\newenvironment{BAR}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                    {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\newenvironment{FOOBAR}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                       {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{FOO}
\end{FOO}
\begin{BAR}
\end{BAR}
\begin{FOOBAR}
\end{FOOBAR}
\begin{FOO}
\begin{BAR}
\begin{FOOBAR}
\end{FOOBAR}
\end{BAR}
\end{FOO}
\end{document}
```

shall deliver console output:

```
FOO-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOO-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOOBAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOOBAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOO-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is FOO
FOOBAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is BAR
FOOBAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is BAR
BAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is FOO
FOO-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
```

Answer (score 9):

Environments are usually called using a `\begin`-`\end` clause. You can patch `\begin` (using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) to store the value of `\@currenvir` before it is updated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\begin}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\@surroundenvir\@currenvir}{}{}

\newenvironment{FOO}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                    {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\newenvironment{BAR}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                    {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\newenvironment{FOOBAR}{\message{\@currenvir-begin: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}%
                       {\message{\@currenvir-end: Surrounding environment's name is \@surroundenvir}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{FOO}
\end{FOO}
\begin{BAR}
\end{BAR}
\begin{FOOBAR}
\end{FOOBAR}
\begin{FOO}
  \begin{BAR}
    \begin{FOOBAR}
    \end{FOOBAR}
  \end{BAR}
\end{FOO}

\end{document}
```

This yields in the `.log`:

```
FOO-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOO-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOOBAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOOBAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
FOO-begin: Surrounding environment's name is document
BAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is FOO
FOOBAR-begin: Surrounding environment's name is BAR
FOOBAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is BAR
BAR-end: Surrounding environment's name is FOO
FOO-end: Surrounding environment's name is document
```

Note that `\@currenvir` defaults to `document`, set inside the [LaTeX2e kernel](https://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx?view=co).

Answer (score 4):

Example "test.tex":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\@surroundenvir{}
\newcommand*\@surroundenvirtemp{}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{FOO}{\let\@surroundenvirtemp=\@currenvir}
\AtBeginEnvironment{FOO}{\let\@surroundenvir=\@surroundenvirtemp}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{BAR}{\let\@surroundenvirtemp=\@currenvir}
\AtBeginEnvironment{BAR}{\let\@surroundenvir=\@surroundenvirtemp}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{FOOBAR}{\let\@surroundenvirtemp=\@currenvir}
\AtBeginEnvironment{FOOBAR}{\let\@surroundenvir=\@surroundenvirtemp}
\newenvironment{FOO}{\message{Begin \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%
                    {\message{End \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%%
\newenvironment{BAR}{\message{Begin \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%
                    {\message{End \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%%
\newenvironment{FOOBAR}{\message{Begin \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%
                       {\message{End \@currenvir: Surrounding env is: \@surroundenvir^^J}}%%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{FOO}
\end{FOO}

\begin{BAR}
\end{BAR}

\begin{FOOBAR}
\end{FOOBAR}

\begin{FOO}
\begin{BAR}
\begin{FOOBAR}
\end{FOOBAR}
\end{BAR}
\end{FOO}


\end{document}
```

[image]